Allow HTML in custom taxonomy description, and show it on front end
Sorry I'm quite new at coding, and also working with WordPress and ACF, and I'm trying my best but I can't figure this out:
I'm trying to load my taxonomy description in rich text. Currently I'm using this code:
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'locatie'); // Get the terms associated with the post
if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) :
foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
<h2><?php echo ($term->name); ?></h2>
<p><?php echo ($term->description); ?></p>
<?php endforeach;
endif;
?>

I want to put in location information, add some line breaks, maybe use HTML, and add a link to Google Maps or something. I downloaded a plugin to enable a rich text editing within the taxonomy, and formatted it correctly. However, the code return is without all the formatting. How can I make sure that the formatted, rich text/html description is loaded?
Any suggestions are more then welcome <3

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79197929/get-taxonomy-description-as-rich-text-or-formatted-text. Please only post on once, on the most appropriate site.

@Caleb I thought these were completely different website haha. Only just figured out it's actually the same company! Sorry!

So after some coding, and some testing and stuff I finally got it working. I noticed that the Term description was being stored in the database as escaped HTML entities (<br>), which means WordPress is storing the <br> tags as text, not as actual HTML.
So I wrote some code to decode the HTML entities to actually bring back the proper  tags!
<?php
// Temporarily remove all filters on term_description
remove_all_filters('term_description');

// Get terms associated with the post
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'locatie'); 
if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) :
    foreach ($terms as $term) :
        // Decode HTML entities to get actual <br> tags
        $decoded_description = html_entity_decode($term->description);
        ?>
        <p>
            <b><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></b><br>
            <?php echo wp_kses_post($decoded_description); ?><br>
            <?php echo esc_html($term->adresveld); ?>
        </p>
    <?php endforeach;
endif;

// Re-add the filters for term_description if needed
add_filter('term_description', 'wpautop');
?>

